# Making an OR statement matter less in a select statement

Tags: mysql

I am writing a select statement to fetch some records i am interested in but the `OR` statement should come last in the pecking order and should be there to improve the other conditions specified.

In this statement for instance

```
select * from the_temp where the_temp_club_id = 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4 AND the_temp_membership_year=2000 AND the_temp_name='one';
```

all records with any of this `the_temp_club_id` - `the_temp_club_id = 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4` are shown,but it shouldn't be that way.Instead,i want the select to show me all the records where `the_temp_name = one` and `the_temp_membership_year=2000` and also show the `the_temp_club_id`.

The select statement should show all the records where `the_temp_name = one` only and the other conditions should be secondary.

Comment: View my posted answer includes fiddle :)

Comment: Thanks Naveen.That was helpful too.

Comment: You are always welcome.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `IN`   better then `OR`

```
   where the_temp_club_id in ( 1,2,3,4)
   AND the_temp_membership_year=2000 AND the_temp_name='one'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Working example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67037/1)

```
SELECT * FROM THE_TEMP 
  WHERE THE_TEMP_CLUB_ID IN (1, 2, 3,4)
  AND THE_TEMP_MEMBERSHIP_YEAR = 2000 
  AND THE_TEMP_NAME = 'one';
```

Answer (score 2):

> The select statement should show all the records where the_temp_name = one only and the other conditions should be secondary.

So you want to select all records where `the_temp_name = one` or records with other conditions. You are probably looking for this:

```
SELECT * FROM the_temp 
WHERE the_temp_name='one'
OR
(
  the_temp_club_id IN (1,2,3,4)
  AND
  the_temp_membership_year=2000
)
```

Comment: I read the query as AND'ing the other two clauses with the IN (1,2,3,4) IN-clause or OR-condition.

Comment: @ThomasW - Sorry I didn't get you.  Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: Sorry, maybe your query is correct -- if you read & follow his "explanation". (Which doesn't match the SQL he gave). Frankly I suspect his logic & query design to be reliable, whatever he thinks he's trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from the_temp where (the_temp_club_id = 1 OR the_temp_club_id = 2 OR the_temp_club_id= 3 OR the_temp_club_id = 4) AND the_temp_membership_year=2000 AND the_temp_name='one';
```

Try This